# VB.net WebBrowser control not handling CSS divs with float

Tags: html, css, vb.net, css-float, webbrowser-control

I made a table on the html page using div tags. The content of the table hides and shows with onClick event on the corresponding Enabled/Disabled section. Everything style related about div sections is made with CSS in a separate stylesheet.

All of the files (html, css, js) are located locally on my disk and they will be mostly accessed locally within the software made in VB.net.

The pages I made look perfect in both Chrome and IE (v11), but when I open them with WebBrowser control it seems as the control is not handling the div elements with float property (*see image bellow*).

Can someone please tell me what the problem is here, as I don't think it's webpage style related, but more of a WebBrowser control related problem?

[image: WebBrowser control and IE screenshot]
*(open image in new tab for better resolution)*

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case if someone comes looking for answers on this topic:

turns out a lot of CSS3 functionality is not supported within VS WebBrowser control. The main issue weren't divs with float property, but the use of calc within width property (`width: calc(...);`). After setting all the CSS width properties to a pre-calculated percentage, the table began to regain it's shape.

There are some other CSS properties not working properly, for instance `display: table; (cell, row, etc.)` and `box-shadow`.

EDIT: I discovered the beauty of Microsoft's idea of emulation behind WebBrowser control. Turns out, even if you have IE11 installed, WebBrowser is dumbed down to IE8 and you have to change/add a registry key in order to enable the IE11 HTML5 and CSS3 functionalities to it.
See: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/793687/Configuring-the-emulation-mode-of-an-Internet-Expl